# Group by and having trouble understanding

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

I was looking at some SQL query that I have in Access database that I did not make.

One of the SQL query goes something like this:

```
select column1 from table1 group by column1 having count(*)>1
```

The purpose of this query is to find the value in `column1` that appears more than once. I can verify that this query works correctly and returns the column value that appears more than once.

I however do not understand why this query works. As per my understanding using `group by` will remove duplicate fields. For instance if column1 had

```
    column1
    apple
    mango
    mango
```

Doing `group by (column1)` will result

```
    column1
    apple
    mango
```

At this point, if we perform `having count(*)>1` or `having count(column1)>1`, it should return no result because group by has already removed the duplicate field. But clearly, I am wrong as the above SQL statement does give the accurate result.

Would you please let me know the problem in my understanding?

**Edit 1:**

Besides the accepted answer, I [this](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations) article which deals with order of SQL operation really helped my understanding

Comment: Having clause works on groups of rows that was formed as a result of grouping. The result of grouping was 2 groups ie apple and mango. On each of these groups we run the having clause. Apple group had 1 row and mango had 2. Thats how it works

Comment: The HAVING criteria will cause only Mango row to return because it is the only group HAVING a count >1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `HAVING` works.  In fact, you can think of it by using subqueries.  Your query is equivalent to:

```
select column1
from (select column1, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      group by column1
     ) as t
having cnt > 1;
```

That is, `having` filters an aggregation query *after* the aggregation has taken place.  However, the aggregation functions are applied *per group*.  So `count(*)` is counting the number of rows in each group.  That is why it is identifying duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`group by` doesn't just remove duplicate values - it returns one row per distinct value of the group by clause, and allows you apply aggregate function per such unique value.

In this query, you actually query the values of `column1` and the result of `count(*)` **per value of column1**, then, you use the `having` clause to return only the values of `column1` that have a `count(*)` greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY clause groups the selection per the fields you mention, on this case column1 but can be a combined column (e.g. column1, column2).
By the way, I think if you run:

```
SELECT column1, Count(*) AS [Count], MIN(column2) AS MinColumn2, MAX(column2) AS MaxColumn2
FROM table1 
GROUP BY column1;
```

Will help you to understand how GROUPING works. When filter by any column directly you may use the WHERE condition but if you want to filter per any field calculated from the grouping you need to use the HAVING clause.